# PayPal Pay-Flow transaction getting failed

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I have tried to make a test transaction using PayPal Advance with below array of request

My Request to PayPal Pay-flow :

```
Array
(
    [PARTNER] => paypal
    [VENDOR] => MyVENDOR
    [USER] => MyUSER
    [PWD] => MyPWD
    [TRXTYPE] => S
    [AMT] => 1
    [CURRENCY] => USD
    [CREATESECURETOKEN] => Y
    [SECURETOKENID] => DF0ej9MfITxolvm32wqQZSE17ONrACck
    [RETURNURL] => http://mywebsite.com/success/
    [CANCELURL] => http://mywebsite.com/payment/
    [ERRORURL] => http://mywebsite.com/payment/
    [BILLTOFIRSTNAME] => test
    [BILLTOLASTNAME] => test
    [BILLTOSTREET] => test
    [BILLTOCITY] => test
    [BILLTOSTATE] => test
    [BILLTOZIP] => test Postal
    [BILLTOCOUNTRY] => Test Country

}
```

Getting Response in $response  :

```
Array
(
    [RESULT] => 0
    [RESPMSG] => Approved
    [SECURETOKEN] => 8aCzrm8u9OkejgNQi13ZPXwsJ
    [SECURETOKENID] => 1rLHxvk4i7S80cqQACUlEY6DNVKnZgBI
)
```

Then loading PayPal transaction window in Iframe as in PayPal docs

```
$securetoken = $response['SECURETOKEN'];
$securetokenid = $response['SECURETOKENID'];

$mode='TEST';

/*mode='LIVE';*/


 <iframe src='https://payflowlink.paypal.com?SECURETOKEN=$securetoken&SECURETOKENID=$securetokenid&MODE=$mode' width='490' height='565' border='0' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'>\n</iframe>
```

But every time i am getting error and transaction getting failed.

```
Declined: 10544-Please use a different payment card.

Declined 1000 Generic host error.
```

and also other error random error like `Your transaction could not be completed`..

I also tried with Live mode and test mode but getting same error.